# insert two or more columns and relate to one row -php -mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to fill in that person's gender and job
If anyone has two or more jobs, how can I add into the database and relate to that person?

[image]

like add driver into list

```
<?php 
$insertjob = sprintf("INSERT INTO `user` (id, name, gender, job) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'],   "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['gender'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['job'],    "text"));
?>
```

thanks

Comment: What about using array?
or make two tables and link them using foreign key.

Comment: consider redesigning your table

Comment: Learn about normalization, one-to-many relationship

Comment: Create a separate table for jobs and connect it to user table using foreign key.

Comment: Here [database normalization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm)

Comment: Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Answer (score 2):

You should may work with two tables.

Do the following thing:

**Table 1: Person**

```
ID | Person | Sex
```

**Table 2: Job**

```
ID | Person_ID | Job
```

Now you can work with the foreign key. If you have a Person, lets name him Jack and say he has two jobs, you can do the following thing:

**In Person Table:**

```
ID | Name | Sex
1  | Jack | m
```

**In Job Table:**

```
ID | Person_ID | Job

1  | 1         | Teacher

2  | 1         | Driver
```

So All you have to do is to reference to the ID of your Person in the `Person_ID` Field in yout Job Table. Then you can simply work with a SQL join.

```
SELECT p.name, p.sex, j.job FROM Person p JOIN Jobs j ON p.id = j.Person_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a separate table for `jobs` and `user_jobs` like:

`job_user` Table

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | job_id |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 5       | 1      |
+----+---------+--------+
| 2  | 5       | 2      |
+----+---------+--------+
| 3  | 5       | 3      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

`jobs` Table

```
+--------+----------+
| job_id | job      |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | teacher  |
+--------+----------+
| 2      | driver   |
+--------+----------+
| 3      | engineer |
+--------+----------+
```

`users` Table

```
+---------+-------+--------+
| user_id | name  | gender |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 1       | John  | m      |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 2       | Jane  | f      |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 3       | Jim   | m      |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 4       | Jones | m      |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 5       | Garry | m      |
+---------+-------+--------+
```

***`HIGHLY DISCOURAGED`*** Or you can just dump `json_encode($_POST['jobs'])`, inside the `jobs` column.